# Django view not returning model to template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Please note that I'm new to Django. I created a simple Configuration model, that I want to use to set some global settings on my site. For right now I created just a theme switching setting that replaces the main css file, but I can't get it to load on my login template. Works fine on the index though. Please assist!

**Views:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from .forms import LoginForm
from .models import Configuration


def get_theme():
    theme_name = Configuration.objects.only('theme_name').get().theme_name
    context = {'theme_name': theme_name}
    return context


def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        user = form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('index')  # Redirect to a success page.
    theme_name = get_theme()
    context = theme_name.update({'login_form': form})
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', context)


def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('registration/login.html')


@login_required(login_url='login/')
def index(request):
    theme_name = get_theme()
    return render(request, 'base.html', theme_name)
```

**Template on Login.html:**

```
{% compress css %}
    <link href="{% static 'base/css/style-'%}{{ theme_name }}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endcompress %}
```

**Template on Base.html (Working):**

```
{% compress css %}
    <link href="{% static 'base/css/style-'%}{{ theme_name }}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{% static 'base/css/sidebar-menu.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endcompress %}
```

As a note: I'm not loading the Base.html on my login page, because the user will need to login before seeing anything on the base.html. If I'm doing this the wrong way, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Edit for forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user or not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry, that login was invalid. Please try again.")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def login(self, request):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you are passing the theme into the context incorrectly, it looks like you intend to include this in every view so you'd be better off adding it as a context processor

```
def theme_name_processor(request):

    theme_name = Configuration.objects.only('theme_name').get().theme_name
    context = {'theme_name': theme_name}
    return context
```

Then add a reference to this to the list of context processors in your settings.

See [Writing your own context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Comment: It looks like a great idea. But this is my first project, and I admittedly don't know what I'm doing. I don't know how to add a context processor yet.

Comment: @JustinBoucher - This is all you need... put this method somewhere then add it to the list of context processors in your settings... i.e `'myapp.wherever.theme_name_processor'`, then it can be used anywhere without having to add it in any view

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors for more information

Answer (score 1):

`theme_name` is missing in the context dictionary you're passing to the template in `login_view`. You're passing: `{'login_form': form}`.

You can extend the dictionary provided by `get_theme()` with additional data, or vice-versa, or you could create a new dictionary from both, and pass that to the template.

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        user = form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('index')  # Redirect to a success page.
    theme_name = get_theme()
    context = theme_name.update({'login_form': form})
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', context)
```

Comment: Yep...still lost. I tried modifying my view to match the one above, but apparently I'm still missing something. Do I need to modify my forms.py file?

Comment: Not that I can see. I made a slight tweak to the answer to assign a new variable, `context` and then pass that to the template.

Comment: Are you certain you have a value for `theme_name` ?

Comment: Yeah...it passes correctly to my index, just not the login.html. I'll update the original question with my forms.py

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working. What I can tell you is that the signature of the `render` function is: request (object), template (string), context (dictionary)

Comment: The way you're calling render in your original sample doesn't match the signature of render.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the theme correctly. It needs to be in the same dictionary as the form.

```
return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'login_form': form, 'theme_name': theme_name})
```

Comment: +1 - theme_name itself its a dictionary though, the `get_theme` method should probably be changed with this to do what it says it does more accurately